# @Qualifier and @Resource doesn't work when running test case under Spring test framework

Tags: spring, testing

I have a test case which has a dependency of 'ticketDao', like below:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class LfnSaleCancellationIntegrationTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
  //@Resource(name = "baseTicketDao")
  private BaseTicketDao ticketDao;
  ....
  public void setTicketDao(@Qualifier("baseTicketDao") BaseTicketDao ticketDao) {
    this.ticketDao = ticketDao;
  }
}
```

and BaseIntegrationTest extends from spring test framework's AbstractJpaTests, Spring is v3.0.5

When run this test case, I got a similar exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No unique bean of type [com.mpos.lottery.te.gamespec.sale.dao.BaseTicketDao] 
is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: 
[baseTicketDao, extraballTicketDao]
```

My project has evolved a long time, in fact when I encountered this exception at the first time, @Qualifier solved it. Till today this project has changed much, but I really have no idea why @Qaulifier and @Resource don't work any more.

And if i remove the dependency of 'ticketDao', the test case will pass. I am wondering whether there are some change of spring configuration cause this exception? or ... i have googled much, but seem no other people ever faced such a problem, pls give your comments, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AbstractJPATests` which is part of old spring test framework and (indirect) subclass of `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests`. By default the injection is not annotation based but it discovers setters and fields and attempts injection by type. It would be recommended to switch to newer annotation based tests, refer to spring documentation for details.

As a workaround try to change autowire mode. Call it in test constructor as `this.setAutowireMode(AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME)`, rename your field to baseTicketDao and remove setter.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that by default the test will be auto wired by type, while in my understanding, if state \@Qualifier explicitly, spring framework will wire by name. The most important is @Qualifier works before, what make it stop to work now.

Comment: To my knowledge in this case annotations would be ignored. I have no clue why @Qualifier worked before (and I seriously doubt it did).

Answer (score 0):

I knew the reason. In my new project, there are a statement of context:component-scan in spring configuration file, which will register 4 BeanPostProcessors by default:

- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(@Autowired)
- RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(@Require)
- CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(JSR-250 annotations, @Resource, @PostConstruct etc,  @WebServiceRef )
- PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(@PersistenceUnit and @PersistenceContext)

While in my old project, only the default BeanPostProcessor(internalAutoProxyCreator) has been registered. My understanding is AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will always wire by type. Anyway if remove context:component-scan, my test case can pass now.

In fact i have migrate all my test cases to spring test context framework now, and context:component-scan must be stated, otherwise @Autowired, @Resource etc annotation will be ignored, and you will get a great many of NullPointerException of those automaticaly injected dependencies.

NOTE: `<context:annotation-config/>` will register those 4 BeanPostProcessors too.